# How to store like objects in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, object

I'm trying to create a collection of objects in my js code, and there are 2 ways that seem both logical. I'm wondering if there's a 'best practise', and why. I couldn't find too much about it, though it seems a fundamental question.

Let's say they're color objects. The hue values are fictional. $ is jQuery.

### Option 1: Identifier as property

This I call 'the database way'; each object looks like a table row and contains all fields that belong to that row.

```
colors = [
  {name: "red", hex: "ff0000", hue: 34},
  {name: "blue", hex: "0000ff", hue: 100}
]
```

add color:

```
colors.push({name: "purple", hex: "ff00ff", hue: 100});
```

get color(s) by specifying name:

```
redObjs = $.grep(colors, function(c){return (c.name === "red");}); //array with 1 element //easier way?
hexOfRex = redObj[0].hex;
```

get color name(s) by specifying hue:

```
hueObjs = $.grep(colors, function(c){return (c.hue === 100);}); //array with 2 elements (color objects)
hueNames = hueObjs.map(function(c){return c.name;}); //array with 2 elements (strings)
```

### Option 2: Identifier as key

Here, part of the information (nl the identifier) is not stored in the color object.

```
colors = {
  red: {hex: "ff0000", hue: 34},
  blue: {hex: "0000ff", hue: 100}
}
```

add color:

```
colors["purple"] = {hex: "ff00ff", hue: 100};
```

get color by specifying name:

```
redObj = colors["red"];
hexOfRed = redObj.hex //or directly colors["red"].hex;
```

get color name(s) by specifying hue:

```
hueNames = []; for (c in colors) {if (colors[c].hue === 100) hueNames.push(c);} //array with 2 elements (strings)
```

I can think of some (dis)advantages for each, like
Option 1 advantages: Uniformity and database-likeness. An array, and not an object, seems a more natural structure to store objects that are so alike. 
Option 2 advantages: Ease and shortness of retrieving information, at least, if name is known. No duplicate color names possible.

But that doesn't really help me pick. Are there any other arguments to consider? Is one right out 'wrong' or considered bad practise, and why? Does it matter if I'll always be having the color name and never need to look it up (which is the main problem for option 2, it seems).

Thanks guys!

Comment: I think http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ is better place for this kind of questions.

Comment: I would add that the first option has the advantage of being easy to loop over.

Comment: Depending on the size of data and the project itself you can abstract this out by implementing some sort of `Collection` to take advantages of both arrays and hashes. For example http://jsfiddle.net/VSz7g/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on the size of data you have, and kind of performance you want.
In most cases,the second optimization won't even matter,unless your data rows start running into few thousands or more.
Try jsperf.com to benchmark both the cases, with a sample data set of exactly the size that you want.
If the peroformance is nearly the same , go with the cleaner data format .

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the scale of this 'database' webSQL may be more appropriate. Otherwise I'd say theres a fair amount to consider. The JS array of arrays model or array of objects model is not very memory or performance efficient( http://0fps.net/2013/05/22/implementing-multidimensional-arrays-in-javascript/ ).

However, if you only intend to access the data by a single identifier the object of objects model is logically the easiest to write and access. Conversely performing a look-up by attribute would be easier and faster on the array of objects method as it's linear list with defined length. You would unfortunately lose the fast identifier reference though.

Both are good practice, but you should be asking yourself which performance hits are acceptable while keeping the code as slimline and maintainable as possible.